# Date Format from model is not working correctly and is Displaying seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, model-view-controller, razor, date-formatting

I'm trying to have a create a date format that displays the MM/DD/YYYY and time. So basically it's I'm trying to display 11/17/2020 9:36AM but my code ends up displaying mm/dd/yyyy --:-- -- when I use the date format [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] within my model. I want to remove the seconds off the date format

When I go to check on dev tools it says The specified value "11/17/2020 9:36 AM" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS". I don't know if there's something wrong with my display format in my model or if there a problem within my razor. If it's neither then what could be the problem and what is the solution?

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Advocate Time Called")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? AdvocateTimeCalled { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col form-group">
        <p class="card-text m-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvocateTimeCalled)
        </p>
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdvocateTimeCalled, new { HtmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdvocateTimeCalled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
   </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Review this site's examples: [https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime](https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)/
I don't think you are wanting the AM/PM designator to be included, but using the {} formatting tag outputs the DateTime to something like "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM".

It may be that you need to use some other code to format the output value, or a combination of them.

I know I didn't provide a cut-n-paste answer, but I hope this helps.